# Compute the left cosets of $\langle (12)\rangle \times \langle[1]\rangle$ in $S_3\times \Bbb Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

Compute the left cosets of $\langle (12)\rangle\times\langle[1]\rangle$ in $S_3\times \Bbb Z_3$

Ok, so I know $\langle (12)\rangle$ is in $S_3$ and $\langle[1]\rangle$ is in $\Bbb Z_3$

Comment: *"Ok, so I know $\langle (12)\rangle$ is in $S_3$ and $\langle [1]\rangle$ is in $\Bbb Z_3$."* **Be careful:** Your use of "is in" is not rigorous. It could be interpreted as, say, $\langle (12)\rangle\in S_3$ or  $\langle (12)\rangle\subseteq S_3$ instead of  $\langle (12)\rangle\le S_3$ (as in  "$\langle (12)\rangle$ is a subgroup of $S_3$").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I multiplying $(12)$ by $[1]$?

No.

Note that $\langle (12)\rangle=\{(1)(2)(3), (12)\}$, whereas $\langle [1]_3\rangle=\{[0]_3, [1]_3, [2]_3\}$. Thus there are six elements in $H=\langle (12)\rangle\times\langle[1]_3\rangle$.

The left cosets of $H$ in your group are of the form

$$(\sigma, [a]_3)H=\{(\tau, [b]_3)\in S_3\times \Bbb Z_3
 \mid (\sigma\tau^{-1}, [a-b]_3)\in H\},$$

noting that $(12)^{-1}=(12)$.

Comment: Is there a different notation for the line starting with sigma? I don't understand that line

Comment: I've removed the $+$. Is that any better? What's the first bit you don't understand, @cele?

Comment: Almost all of it. I don't understand what sigma and $[a]_3$ represent, not tau and $[b]_3$ I'm assuming they represent elements in $S_3$ and $\BbbZ_3$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, they are elements of $S_3$ and $\Bbb Z_3$, respectively, @cele. In general, for any sets $A$ and $B$, we have  $$A\times B=\{(a, b)\mid a\in A\land b\in B\}.$$

Comment: So then what does the $\sigma \tau^{-1}, [a-b]_3$ notation mean

Comment: It means, @cele, that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ differ only by an element in $\langle (12)\rangle$ and $[a]_3-_3[b]_3:=[a-b]_3$ means that $[a]_3$ and $[b]_3$ differ only by an element of $\Bbb Z_3$.

Comment: Also, $H$ is a Cartesian product, like $A\times B$.

Comment: Why is $\langle (12) \rangle$ = ${(1)(2),(12)$?? Isn’t $(12)$ the permutation where 1 goes to 2, 2 hoes to 1, and 3 maps to itself?

Comment: Yes, well-spotted, @cele; I've made a correction now.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers, @cele $\ddot\smile$